# Batch file to rename files with complex names and back again

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

Reviving an old topic once discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098010/batch-file-to-rename-files-in-a-folder-and-back-again/), as I have a similar problem. The solution proposed in the old thread worked only in half in my case.

I need first to rename various media files (mp4, mp3, wav...) with irregular, sometimes complex names as 1.mp3, 2.mp4, 3.wav, etc. And some time after I need to restore the original filenames. File extensions should remain the same in both cases.

In a more specific case of renaming .raw files [Helbreder proposed two .bat scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098010/batch-file-to-rename-files-in-a-folder-and-back-again/). The first .bat changes filenames to 1.raw, 2.raw, 3.raw, etc. and creates corresponding individual .txt files each of which keeps the original filename. The second .bat takes the original filenames from individual .txt files and renames 1.raw, 2.raw, 3.raw, etc., back to the original.

For my purpose I slightly modified the first .bat proposed, and this works perfectly well:

```
@echo OFF
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


set I=1

for %%G in (*.mp3 or *.3gp or *.wav or .mp4) do (
    set ORIGINAL_NAME=%%~nG
    set ORIGINAL_EXTENSION=%%~xG
    ( 
        REM Try to rename file
        ren "%%G" "!I!"!ORIGINAL_EXTENSION!
    ) && (
        REM Renaming was successful
        > "!I!.txt" echo !ORIGINAL_NAME!!ORIGINAL_EXTENSION!
        set /A I+=1
    ) || (
        REM Renaming was a failure
        echo Cannot rename [!ORIGINAL_NAME!] file.
    )
)

@endlocal
```

Put in a destination directory, this .bat renames all media files, keeping the correct extensions, and generates a set of .txt files each of which contains the original filename with extension.

For instance, 1.txt contains a string "Play 2019-03-06 in C.mp3" which was the original filename.

Then I need to reverse the original filenames and I run the second unmodified Helbreder's .bat. For commodity purpose I paste it here:

```
@echo OFF
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


for %%F in (*.txt) do (
    set BASENAME=%%~nF
    REM Read original name from txt file
    for /F %%G in (%%F) do (
        REM iterate over all corresponding files
        for %%H in (!BASENAME!.*) do (
            set EXTENSION=%%~xH
            REM Remove dot from extension string
            set EXTENSION=!EXTENSION:~1!
            if not "!EXTENSION!" == "txt" (
                REM Process files
                (
                    REM try to rename corresponding file to old name
                    ren "!BASENAME!.!EXTENSION!" "%%G.!EXTENSION!"
                ) && (
                    REM Operation was successful - remove TXT file
                    del /F /Q "%%F"
                ) || (
                    REM Something went wrong
                    echo Cannot restore old name for file [!BASENAME!.!EXTENSION!].
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

@endlocal
```

As my filenames may be complex and often include blank spaces, this second .bat works in a half-successful way.

It reverted the first original filename "Play 2019-03-06 in C.mp3"  written to a 1.txt with extension, as simply "Play.mp3". It also ignored a part of the second complex filename which followed blank space, keeping only "2007-03-06.mp3" instead of "2007-03-06 output.mp3". And it successfully reverted only those filenames which were composed of numbers and underscores, without blank spaces.

As far as I understand, the issue consists in the way the second .bat retrieves the filename from the text string kept in .txt file. The first blank space occurring in the text line is considered as the end of a filename.

Could you kindly suggest a solution for reverse renaming of *any* files from the correspondent .txt record, which may contain letters, numbers and blank spaces (and maybe special characters, like "&" and some others).

Comment: Your first example code has issues, which would prevent me from advising anyone to run it. At that point, I stopped reading the rest of your question. Obviously, I wouldn't want to work on whatever has been created by running the bad code prior to it.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reaction. I am new in batch coding and might add some errors to the original code. Notwithstanding the issues, the code seems to work well. On the contrary, the second one does its job only for filenames without spaces. Could you suggest a way to bypass this problem?

Comment: As I said, I wasn't wanting to read past your first code sample. Lines `2`, `8`, `9` and `23` should be removed, line `7` is just completely wrong, and lines `12`, `15` and `19` should be modified. Personally, I'd remove line `10` and modify `line `13` too. Taking a quick look at the bottom code, I would change almost every part of it, it's pretty awful.

Comment: Thank you! I am afraid, my understanding of batch language is not good enough to translate your suggestion into a working code. But I will make a try.

Comment: If I were you, I'd look at the other, and better voted, answers in your linked question, to base any code upon. Just completely forget about that chosen code. (It would essentially need so much changing).

Answer (score 0):

Following Compo's advise I tried another code from [the old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098010/batch-file-to-rename-files-in-a-folder-and-back-again/), this time proposed by Jeb.

After a slight modification to make it match to different file types and - important! - to keep their original extensions, the code seems to work, but with issues.

1. When there is more than one dot in the filename the name revert code does not restore it completely, even though it is correctly saved in the .txt file by the rename batch. For example the second batch truncates "Play 2020.10.12.mp4" to "Play 2020" and does not wish to restore the extension.
2. Placed in directories with many files the rename batch sometimes does not rename a part of the list, sometimes does not do the job at all and sometimes renames all files flawlessly. I first thought the partial script dysfunction might be related to the presence of special signs in the filenames, like commas or parenthesis. But no, when I delete special signs, this changes nothing. Just puzzled.

So, the new version of code is only partially solving the problem. Is there something to correct in the code, to make it more universally working? Which solution could be applied in these two cases?

I divided the code into two separate .bat files to rename and to revert original filenames.

The both follow.

Rename:

```
@echo off
set cnt=0
del Names.txt > nul 2>&1
echo Running Batch Rename
for %%f in (*.mp3 or *.mp4 or *.3gp or *.wav) do (
    set "file=%%f"
    set "EXTENSION=%%~xf"
    CALL :renameToNumber
)

:renameToNumber
set /A cnt+=1
set "number=00000%cnt%"
set "number=%number:~-4%"
(echo %number% %file%) >> Names.txt
ren "%file%" %number%"%EXTENSION%"
exit /b
```

Revert the original names:

```
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%A in (names.txt) DO (
   set "number=%%A"
   set "filename=%%~nB"
   call ren %%number%%.* "%%filename%%.*"
   call echo ren %%number%%.* "%%filename%%.*"
)
exit /b
```